# Merge values in a single column based on the primary column value being non blank in Excel

Tags: excel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiR8h.jpg

I need to check for the first column in an excel file and if it is non blank, then combine all the non blank rows in another column into a single cell with spaces between them. For example, in the given sample, for serial no 2, I have to merge lines 3,4,5 only in column "log" so that the Log value for the 2nd entry (Serial no 2) becomes **Success in 1st Experiment Failure in 3rd experiment Success in 5th experiment**

Comment: Have you tried using any VBA or were you looking to have this done with some sort of formula?

Comment: I have no experience with VBA or excel, I just wanted this part done so I can go ahead with importing it into a database and then having fun with the data. Thanks!

Comment: So you are blatantly admitting you want someone to do this for you!

Comment: I am sorry, but I tried using merge and center formula in excel and tried  googling my query, but I could not come up with any satisfactory result. All the other examples on internet cover merging entire rows based on a column attribute, not certain column values. Thanks!

Comment: Asking isn't the problem, the problem is how much information must be provided, if you don't know about VBA the answer can't be given in VBA, my knowledge doesn't contain anyway to do what you're asking without VBA. Granted I could post the code but then I've got to explain how to use it, how to debug, it can get messy.

Comment: If this is only a one-off rather than a regular process you can use my favorite low hanging fruit. Paste your sheet as text into word. Replace All "^p^t^t" with "^t". Copy as text back to excel. This will remove a line break and 2 tabs and replace it with 1 tab, effectively moving any column C item with nothing in column A or B, into column D of the previous line. If you want to merge the cells you would replace for " " rather than a tab.

Answer (score 1):

Tested this with your sample data, this will be my last post to this question

```
Public Sub Answer()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Data As Variant
Dim Row As Integer
Dim dRow As Integer
Dim DelRange As Range

' change sheet4 to the name of your worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
' change A2:C8 to the range of your data (yes there are simpler ways to do this)
Data = Range("A1:C8")

Row = 2
Do
   dRow = Row
   Row = Row + 1
   Do While Data(Row, 1) = ""
      If Data(Row, 3) <> "" Then
         Data(dRow, 3) = Data(dRow, 3) & " " & Data(Row, 3)
         If DelRange Is Nothing Then
            Set DelRange = ws.Rows(Row)
         Else
            Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, ws.Rows(Row))
         End If
      End If
      Row = Row + 1
      If Row > UBound(Data, 1) Then Exit Do
   Loop

Loop Until Row >= (UBound(Data, 1) - 1)

Range("A1:C8") = Data
DelRange.Delete

End Sub
```